# Passenger missing gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, passenger, mod-rails

I'm a newbie to Rails development and trying to run my new application on Hostmonster.
I managed to make it work at the beginning. But now I tried to add more features and it's broken with the following error:

> Missing these required gems: paperclip You're running: ruby 1.8.7.358
>   at /usr/bin/ruby rubygems 1.7.2 at /home1/kundkhu/ruby/gems/gems,
>   /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems, /home1/examplec/ruby/gems Run `rake
>   gems:install` to install the missing gems.

gem list --local

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
[...]
paperclip (2.7.0)
rack (1.1.6)
rails (2.3.11)
rake (0.8.7)
```

ls -l /home1/kundkhu/ruby/gems/gems

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 kundkhu kundkhu 4096 Jun  4 05:43 paperclip-2.7.0/
drwxr-xr-x  7 kundkhu kundkhu 4096 May 25 03:47 rack-1.1.6/
drwxr-xr-x 11 kundkhu kundkhu 4096 May 25 03:47 rails-2.3.11/
drwxr-xr-x  6 kundkhu kundkhu 4096 May 25 04:30 rake-0.8.7/
```

It looks like apache user has read permission to the folders.

`rake gems:install` runs without error and does nothing.

I've been looking at it for hours now and ran out of ideas. What am I missing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rake gems:unpack` was the solution. It copied the gem to the vendor folder where the Passenger found it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your app is running as [the wrong user](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_caveats_amp_troubleshooting).

Comment: It's a hosted environment. I can't change the apache or passenger config. It looks like the whole world has read access to the gems. 
They shouldn't need more, I think.